# WordPress and PHP | Check if row exists in database if yes don't insert data

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm fairly new to WordPress and SQL. I have a contact form that I want to have the data be submitted to my WordPress database but only if the data that has been entered has not been entered before.

This is what i have so far, which sends data to my database when form is submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['contact_us'])) {
    $invalidContact = "<h5 class='invalidBooking'> Nope try again</h5>";
    $successContact = "<h5 class='invalidBooking'> Message Sent!</h5>";
    $table_name='contact_table';
    global $wpdb;

    $contact_name = esc_attr($_POST['contact_name']);
    $contact_email = sanitize_email($_POST['contact_email']);
    $subject = esc_attr($_POST['subject']);
    $message = esc_attr($_POST['message']);

    $error= array();


    if (empty($contact_name)) {
        $error['name_invalid']= "Name required";
    }
    if (empty($contact_email)){
        $error['email_invaild']= "Email required";
    }

    // Im guessing some code here to check if row exists in database

    if (count($error) >= 1) {
        echo $invalid;
    }
    if (count($error) == 0) {
        $data_array=array(
            'Contact_Name'=>$contact_name,
            'Contact_Email'=> $contact_email,
            'Contact_Subject'=> $subject,
            'Contact_Message'=> $message,
        );

        $rowResult=$wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_array,$format=NULL);
        echo $successContact;
    } 

}
```

Comment: The answer below might be what you want , but more important is that based on what you want to find if data entered before has not been entered before. By checking email ? contact name ? or post subject? ...  For example if checking by email, you mean you only expect them to submit form only 1 time, they can't submit other form on different days using same email for different purpose?

Comment: Yes? I'm not sure if I want is even possible right now. 
So the user can submit the form multiple times as long as all the fields don't match what they have entered before. Like the first time a user submits a form should be all good but if they try to submit again with all the same info it wont work, but if they make one of the fields different it will be fine.

Comment: Ok if thats the case then use the codes from the answer below, then put all the columns in `WHERE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch data using this code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table WHERE column = 1";
echo $query;
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

and then you know what to do...

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm using this code correctly. I tested it by changing column = 1 to Contact_Email = $contact_email but still not working? 
Sorry, Im a total newbie. Like how do you fetch the data? The way i've tried gives me a blank screen.

Comment: echo query and run it through phpmyadmin. if you are getting the data then query is ok. and also place this line in wp_config.php file define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: @ParthShah  how to echo query? where is $query?

Comment: the query your passing in get_results function. check my answer I just update it.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this code

```
if (count($error) == 0) {
    $data_array=array(
        'Contact_Name'=>$contact_name,
        'Contact_Email'=> $contact_email,
        'Contact_Subject'=> $subject,
        'Contact_Message'=> $message,
    );

 $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE 'Contact_Name'= '$contact_name' AND 'Contact_Email' = '$contact_email' AND 'Contact_Subject' = '$subject' AND 'Contact_Message' = '$message'";
 $query_results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
 if(count($query_results) == 0) {
    $rowResult=$wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_array,$format=NULL);
 }
}
```

Hope this works for you.